# I want the Cloth to drape over the cup, but It creates gap between them

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, cloth-simulation, collision

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me why this happens? I created a plane, subdivided it to 50, and smoothed it, and went to the physics, and clicked on cloth, then selected the cup, saucer and plane and went to physics and clicked on collision, but when I play the animation, it gets space from the cup.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the "inner" and "outer" values from the *Collision* settings of the vase.

A good value should be around 1/100th of the vase width (that you can check by selecting the vase and hitting <kbd>N</kbd> while in the 3d viewport: look under "dimensions") or anyway at least 1/10th of what you have now. You'll need some trial and error anyway.

PS increase the cloth *Steps* to ~10 and the cloth collision *Quality* to at least 3 or you'll risk the cloth to go through the vase.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, dimensions are: x=12.2  y=12.2  z= 11.8 , can you please tell me how much should be inner and how much outer? I couldn't do it myself

Comment: Try 0.05 and 0.02 and see if it gets better

Comment: Please see this one https://i.imgur.com/XAMCjP9.jpg and this one   https://i.imgur.com/V5ESU0O.png  first one is cloth selected and second one is cup selected, I changed the values, but still don't works

Comment: Oh you didn't mention it was centimeters :) Then I suggest 0.001 and 0.001 or to select your vase and hit Ctrl+A, then "apply scale".

Comment: this is what I did: https://i.imgur.com/B94zved.jpg , actually I made cloth again, the first one got deleted from me, so I made inner&outer to 0.001, the gap reduced little bit, then I reduced the collision distance, it become more better but not perfect. please look at the Image its difficult to explain here. I am kind of new to blender, so please explain your answer a little so that I get the point. Thanks